# Outliner - show only hidden

Tags: outliner

Little things in Blender that could drive someone crazy. I have a lot of objects in the scene, some of them marked as restricted visibility. Before the render I want to "unhide" them all - not to search them one by one...
Is it possible? It should be much more intuitive this kind of most obvious things...

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Press <kbd>A</kbd> until everything is selected. If you have anything selected before pressing <kbd>A</kbd> you will have to press it twice, otherwise only once. (This will select the hidden objects as well so don't worry about them for now.)</strike>
**Edit:** As Mr. Zak pointed out in the comments section, it is unnecessary to select everything.

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd> to unhide everything.

You can also navigate to the `Object` menu at the bottom of the View3D window, select `Show / Hide` and select `Show Hidden`. This may be helpful if, like OP, you have issues with the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key combination. Practically everything in Blender has a button somewhere.
[image: Example]

Comment: Selecting all objects isn't needed to unhide hidden ones.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Ubuntu/Unity. Maybe a problem due to the "alt" problem in unity...

Comment: @LDCO You can also go to the Object menu at the bottom of the View3D window > Show / Hide > Show Hidden. Practically everything in Blender has a button.

Comment: thanx.... sometimes it's so not intuitive, and I working in Blender for 5 years...

Comment: @LDCO It is sometimes difficult to find. Glad I could help.

Comment: It's not exactly "find"... It's find a workaround... It's not possible to do it from the outline although it's so logic from the UI point of view...